# C# - How to 3D stack objects in a 3 dimensional space?

Tags: c#, algorithm

The purpose of my algorithm is to stack containers on a ship. 
I will explain how I modelled my 3D space to make the question more clear.

A ship has a container table. The container table contains container rows.

```
public class ContainerTable : IContainerTable
{
    public List<IContainerRow> Rows { get; set;}

    public ContainerTable()
    {
        Rows = new List<IContainerRow>();
    }
}
```

The index of the container row list determines the column of the container table and each column has a container stack.

```
public class ContainerRow : IContainerRow
{
    public List<IContainerStack> ContainerStack { get; set; }

    public ContainerRow()
    {
        ContainerStack = new List<IContainerStack>();
    }
}
```

The container stack determines the containers stacked vertically from bottom to top.

```
public class ContainerStack : IContainerStack
{
    public List<IContainer> Containers { get; set; }
    public int WeightOfStack { get; set; }

    public ContainerStack(List<IContainer> containers)
    {
        Containers = containers;
    }
}
```

The algorithm auto generates a table based on the ship length and ship width.

```
public IContainerTable GetNewContainerTable(int shipLength, int shipWidth)
{
    IContainerTable table = new ContainerTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
    {
        IContainerRow row = ContainerRow();
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        for (int j = 0; j < shipWidth; j++)
        {
            IContainerStack stack = ContainerStack();
            table.Rows[i].ContainerStack.Add(stack);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

**Here is where I ran into problems.**

The algorithm loops through each row and adds a container to each column. It repeats from the beginning if there are still containers left.

```
public IContainerTable AssignContainersToShip(List<IContainer> containers)
{
    //Represents the unsorted container list index.
    int i = 0;
    //Represents the table column
    int j = 0;

    while (i < containers.Count)
    {
        //Loop through each row.
        foreach (var row in _table.Rows)
        {
            //Loop through each column
            foreach (IContainerStack stack in _table.Rows[j].ContainerStack)
            {
                stack.Containers.Add(containers[i]);
                i++;
                //Go to the next column.
                if (j < _table.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    j++;
                }
                //Start from the first column when looping through the second row.
                else 
                {
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _table;
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**
So, if we assume that the ship has a 2x2 table a input of 4 containers the result should be:
*Row 1*:
 - Column 1: Container 1
 
 - Column 2: Container 2

*Row 2*:
 - Column 1: Container 3
 
 - Column 2: Container 4

**Actual Result:**
*Row 1*:
 - Column 1: Container 1, Container 3
 - Column 2: Container 2, Container 4

*Row 2*:
 - Column 1: Empty
 - Column 2: Empty

I'm a bit lost with this result. The algorithm only stacks containers on the first row and I want it to divide the containers equally over each ship row. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You set j to 0 always inside the inner loop; don't you need an `if` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IContainerTable AssignContainersToShip(List<IContainer> containers)
{
    //Represents the unsorted container list index.
    int i = 0;
    //Represents the table column
    int j = 0;

    while (i < containers.Count)
    {
        //Loop through each row.
        foreach (var row in _table.Rows)
        {
            //Loop through each column
            foreach (IContainerStack stack in _table.Rows[j].ContainerStack)
            {
                stack.Containers.Add(containers[i]);
                i++;                
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return _table;
}
```